# Opencart category.php not updating price

Tags: php, opencart

Working on a site with open cart where by I want to display each of my options with its adjusted price.

In the controller I am fetcing all the options, looping over them, and doing a simple addition/formatting of the end result. However its just not working, and I have absolutely no idea why. The price when rendering out to the template, does not show result price + 123.

My code is as follows.

```
$options = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($result['product_id']);

            foreach ($options as $option) {
                foreach($option['option_value'] as $option_value) {
                    $option_value['price'] = $result['price'] = $option_value['price'];
                }
            }

            $this->data['products'][] = array(
                'options'     => $options,
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,
                'name'        => $result['name'],
                'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, 100) . '..',
                'price'       => $price,
                'special'     => $special,
                'tax'         => $tax,
                'rating'      => $result['rating'],
                'reviews'     => sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$result['reviews']),
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&product_id=' . $result['product_id'] . $url)
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$option_value['price'] = $result['price'] = $option_value['price'];
```

should actually be

```
$option_value['price'] = $result['price'] + $option_value['price'];
```

Though if you want to make sure you include the special price too, you could use

```
$option_value['price'] = $option_value['price'] + (empty($result['special']) ? $result['price'] : $result['special']);
```